# Android Canvas drawLine not drawing on MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, canvas, draw

I want to draw a line on the Main Activity using Canvas. The problem is, it is not drawing anything. I have the following code:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1920, 1080, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

float left = 20;
float top = 20;
float right = 50;
float bottom = 100;

canvas.drawLine(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
```

Comment: why do you think it does not draw anything?

Comment: The line is drawn into your canvas. That does not necessearily mean it will be displayed on your device screen.

Comment: @Lamorak So how would I display it on the screen then?

Comment: @pskink bcus I don't see anything?

Comment: what do you want to see?  your Bitmap?  did you use any ImageView or similar View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can display the bitmap like that:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, positionX, positionY, paint);
```

in your case you can try somthing like this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

but you need to use a diffrent canvas for it. The canvas wich let you draw stuff on your screen will be passed to your onDraw() method in your View. So you need to make a View class first and add it in your MainActivity.

You can do that like this:
First you create a class called MyView and add this code to it:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    Bitmap bitmap;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1920, 1080, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        float left = 20;
        float top = 20;
        float right = 50;
        float bottom = 100;

        canvas.drawLine(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

then you change the code in your onCreate() method in your MainActivity to this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    MyView myView = new MyView(this);
    setContentView(myView);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to draw the canvas onto the activity_main.xml, together with some TextView and Buttons and so forth?

Comment: You can add this view to your layout like any other

Comment: when using a custom view you dont need any Bitmap at all draw your stuff in onDraw directly...

Comment: if you want to add this view you can use this function addContentView(myView); instead of the setContentView method and yes you dont need to create a bitmap to draw a line you can just draw a line with canvas.drawLine(...) in the onDraw() method. (like Lamorak posted)

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class like this

```
public class MyView extends View {
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

    float left = 20;
    float top = 20;
    float right = 50;
    float bottom = 100;

    canvas.drawLine(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
}
}
```