# Problems about drawing pictures on SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, canvas

I want to draw pictures on Android with SurfaceView. In fact, I don't know if I need SurfaceView or not.
1.I want to know how android work with canvas. I draw something on the canvas with API:LockCanvas DrawPath UnlockCanvasAndPost and then I draw another Path. However, the previous Path disappears. Could anyone explain why?
2.I get a solution to keep the previous Path by adding the previous Path to the current one. But I wonder the efficiency as I paint all Paths every time. Is there any need for me to marry about this?
3.I want to paint on a remote device indeed. That mean when I paint on my own device, a remote device can get the same paint. Could you please give me some advice about how to work it out?
Thx, Charlie

Comment: You could draw to a bitmap and then send it to another device to display it there as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28793270/android-canvas-drawline-not-drawing-on-mainactivity/28793975#28793975

Comment: Hm..I think I did not describe my goal properly. I want to show the remote device user what I draw with no delay so that the remote device user can see the process while I am drawing.